# Node.js: Error importing module in app.js but file exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I am encountering an error in my Node.js application where I'm trying to import a module in `app.js` from `db.js`, but it's failing with the error message:

```bash
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'path/src/db' imported from /path/src/app.js
```

However, the `db.js` file exists in the specified directory.

`app.js`

```js
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import './db'

// Execute express
const app = express();

// Define PORT
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8001;

//Middlewares
dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome buddy!');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App running on http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```

`db.js`

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

// connect to the database
mongoose
    .connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URI}`, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, // Timeout after 5s
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('successfully connected to the db!');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('failed to connect with db!', err);
    });
```

I've ensured that both files are in the correct directory. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

if I move the database connection code directly into `app.js`, it works without any issues.

Comment: what are you trying to import? You have not exported anything from db.js

Comment: @RaviYadav I am trying to include db.js file inside app.js

Comment: Dinesh, check my answer. Basically you can not directly import a file just by writing its path. You should first export from one module and then import into other module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should export mongoose connection as a function from `db.js` and then use it in `app.js`

in db.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

// connect to the database
const connectDb = async () => {
      mongoose
        .connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URI}`, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, // Timeout after 5s
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('successfully connected to the db!');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('failed to connect with db!', err);
        });
}
     
module.exports = {connectDb};
```

And use it in `app.js`:

```
import { connectDb } from '.path-to-file/db';
connectDb();
```

Comment: Export the connectDb as export const connectDb. Additionally, I require modifying the file import path to '.path-to-file/db.js', and this will function properly.